# How can I use i3 Window manager with KDE 5

Tags: i3-window-manager, kde-plasma-5

How can I use i3 Window manager with KDE 5?

I recently installed KDE 5.15 on Arch Linux and cannot switch window manager to i3.

I also installed i3 for KDE from AUR. I tried solutions like [this](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/2939/i3wm-and-kde-together/) and set environmental variable in .xinitrc as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616473/can-i-get-a-proper-tiling-window-manager-in-kde), but had no luck so far.

Comment: I hope you figured it out, but if not (or for others). The link you referenced above(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616473/can-i-get-a-proper-tiling-window-manager-in-kde), says the environment variable is KDE_WM. NO! The correct environment variable is KDEWM

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a [blog post to cover this topic](https://ryanlue.com/posts/2019-06-13-kde-i3). Melkor33's solution works, but it's not very clean, IMO (to revert to plain Plasma, you have to go in and edit a configuration file); I believe my approach is more "correct", even if it is a smidge more work.

If you've already got i3 installed (I recommend [i3-gaps](https://github.com/Airblader/i3)), it basically boils down to two steps: 1) configure i3 to be Plasma-friendly, and 2) configure your display manager (login screen) to add an option for Plasma + i3.

#### Configure i3 to be Plasma-friendly

Add the following lines to `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
# Don’t treat Plasma pop-ups as full-sized windows
for_window [class="plasmashell"] floating enable

# Don’t spawn an empty window for the Plasma Desktop
for_window [title="Desktop — Plasma"] kill, floating enable, border none
```

#### Configure your display manager to add an option for Plasma + i3

I use sddm (default on Debian), so if you're using another display manager (`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`), you'll have to look into the configuration options.

```
# Create a plasma + i3 launcher script
$ echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n\nKDEWM=/usr/bin/i3 startkde" > /usr/local/bin/startkde-i3
$ sudo chown root.staff /usr/local/bin/startkde-i3
$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/startkde-i3

# Create a custom desktop sessions directory
$ sudo cp -a /usr/share/xsessions /usr/local/share/xsessions

# Create a new desktop session file for plasma + i3
$ cp /usr/local/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop /usr/local/share/xsessions/plasma-i3.desktop
$ sudo sed -i 's|/usr/bin/startkde|/usr/local/bin/startkde-i3|' /usr/share/xsessions/plasma-i3.desktop
$ sudo sed -i '/Name.*=/ s/$/-i3/' /usr/share/xsessions/plasma-i3.desktop

# Configure sddm (the login screen) to use our new desktop sessions directory
$ echo -e "\n\n[X11]\nSessionDir=/usr/local/share/xsessions" | sudo tee -a /etc/sddm.conf
```

Comment: Worth noting, [there's another tutorial](https://github.com/heckelson/i3-and-kde-plasma), it is much cleaner IMO because it considers various corner cases. And it's contributable too :) Works for me, I'm writing this from a freshly configured KDE + i3, so far everything is nice and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable if you create the following file:

```
~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/wm.sh
```

which contains the line

```
export KDEWM=i3wm
```

(got the answer from [this github project](https://github.com/sLite/i3-config) which is probably worth checking out if you're interested in KDE + i3)